# React Typescript and Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to set up Jest in an React app using Typescript.

My set up is like this

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-tdd-ts",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.23",
    "@types/node": "12.12.9",
    "@types/react": "16.9.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "typescript": "3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.3",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.1",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0"
  }
}
```

My App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

import Footer from "./components/Footer";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My Footer.tsx

```
import React from "react";

const Footer: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <hr />
      <span>Text here</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

My Footer.test.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Footer from "./Footer";

it("should render text", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Footer />);
  const span = wrapper.find("span");
  const result = span.text();

  expect(result).toBe("Text here");
});
```

MY setupTest.tsx

```
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

In the terminal I'm getting the following error

```
 PASS  src/App.test.tsx
 FAIL  src/components/Footer.test.tsx
  ● should render text


      Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none.
      To configure an adapter, you should call `Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })`
      before using any of Enzyme's top level APIs, where `Adapter` is the adapter
      corresponding to the library currently being tested. For example:

      import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';

      To find out more about this, see http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/index.html

  4 | 
  5 | it("should render text", () => {
> 6 |   const wrapper = shallow(<Footer />);
    |                   ^
  7 |   const span = wrapper.find("span");
  8 |   const result = span.text();
  9 | 


  at validateAdapter (node_modules/enzyme/src/validateAdapter.js:5:11)
  at getAdapter (node_modules/enzyme/src/getAdapter.js:10:3)
  at makeShallowOptions (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:345:19)
  at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:379:21)
  at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/src/shallow.js:10:10)
  at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/components/Footer.test.tsx:6:19)
```

Sorry I don't have a working demo but can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.
Is there a different way to set up enzyme and Jest when using typescript

Comment: I wonder if it has smth to do with `setupTest` having `tsx` extension. Try changing it to `ts` or even `js` since you're not really using any types there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need this in the test file

```
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

it was posted here but then removed